# Reflect struct with struct methods

Tags: go

I'm playing around with reflect and I'm trying to reflect a struct, create a new one and try to call it.

The variables are working fine but when I reflect a new struct, the struct methods are not copied?

I created a simple example on the playground. On line 34 I receive that 0 Methods exist, but there should be 1 (SetName). Am I doing something wrong? already google for it since hours but do not get any solutions.

https://play.golang.org/p/yArjVLtWEaG

Thanks in advance
cheers pat

Comment: `*company` has a `SetName` method; `company` does not.

Comment: What do you mean when you talk about calling a struct?

Answer (score 2):

SetName is not a method of type company but of type *company. Sou you must create a pointer to company.

Comment: thank you very much... i already banged my head against the wall :)